# What does ABE mean?

Tags: firefox, blocking

What is ABE?

Context is using [Firefox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Firefox) and opening a link in a Google search. Firefox or [NoScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoScript) is displaying:

> ... "filtered by ABE: LOCAL  Deny"

Platform: Firefox 3.5.3, Windows XP 64 bit, NoScript 1.9.8.86

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ABE stands for Application Boundaries Enforcer and is part of NoScript. More information on ABE can be found [here.](http://noscript.net/abe/)

Answer (score 2):

Application Boundaries Enforcer:

http://noscript.net/abe/